# How would I put the sculpt brush menu inside of an operator? So it can be a popup

Tags: scripting

So I attempted to right click locate source and use the line for the brush here

```
 toolsettings = context.tool_settings
 settings = self.paint_settings(context)
 brush = settings.brush
 layout.template_ID_preview(settings, "brush")
```

However I dont think I am understanding how it works. I figured it would be as easy as the matcap which was just this.

```
view = context.space_data
layout.template_icon_view(view, "matcap_icon")
```

Here's an example of how I wanted to put it in an operator. 
[image]